# How to schedule Azure Database import?

Tags: database, azure

We have a weekly development build which I push out to our testing environment setup on Azure. Now I would like to always grab the latest productive database to have fresh data and immediatly see any occuring problems.

How can I automate Azure Database import/restore? Bacpac export on the productive environment is running fine and I can import it to my local database or manually in Azure.

I've seen the possibility to trigger a database restore over the REST API but only PointInTime not pointing to different .bacpac.

Next there is DACFx but there must be some tool around which already does this before writting this myself.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should look at sqlpackage.exe it is basically a wrapper around the DacFx Api and will let you publish a bacpac to azure from the command line so you can include it in your build:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh550080%28v=vs.103%29.aspx